# Why does pdb sometimes skip stepping into multi-part conditional?

Tags: python, pdb

I have a Minimal Working Example code :

`test.py :`

```
a = 4
b = 6
l = [4, 6, 7, 8]
for t in l :
    if t == a or t == b:
        continue
    print(t)
```

I am stepping through the code using `pdb` (`python-3.9.2`) :

```
local: ~ $ python -m pdb test.py
> test.py(1)<module>()
-> a = 4
(Pdb) b 5
Breakpoint 1 at test.py:5
(Pdb) c
> test.py(5)<module>()
-> if t == a or t == b:
(Pdb) p t,a
(4, 4)
(Pdb) p t == a
True
(Pdb) t == a or t == b
True
(Pdb) n                    #### <<--- Conditional is True, why doesn't it explicitly step into it?
> test.py(4)<module>()
-> for t in l :
(Pdb) n
> test.py(5)<module>()
-> if t == a or t == b:
(Pdb) p t==a, t==b
(False, True)
(Pdb) t == a or t == b
True
(Pdb) n                    #### <<--- Conditional is True, and it explicitly steps into it
> test.py(6)<module>()
-> continue
(Pdb) t == a or t == b
True
```

QUESTION :

1. Why does `pdb` explicitly step into the conditional (i.e. it explicitly goes to line 6, the `continue` statement) when `t==b` and not when `t==a`?  Is this an optimization?

Comment: Something's preventing the tracing mechanism from issuing `'line'` trace events for the `continue` line, but I'm not sure what. The problem seems to be gone on Python 3.10.

Comment: ...oh, wait, I was misreading the `dis` output. It's actually not going to that line at all on 3.9. I got confused because there was a POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE with argument 20 on both 3.9 and 3.10, but that 20 actually represents a completely different jump target on 3.9 and 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

When the `t == a` check passes, the bytecode jumps straight back to the `for` line, skipping the `continue`.

Here's the output you get if you examine the bytecode with `dis.dis` on CPython 3.9:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (4)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (6)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

  3           8 BUILD_LIST               0
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ((4, 6, 7, 8))
             12 LIST_EXTEND              1
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (l)

  4          16 LOAD_NAME                2 (l)
             18 GET_ITER
        >>   20 FOR_ITER                30 (to 52)
             22 STORE_NAME               3 (t)

  5          24 LOAD_NAME                3 (t)
             26 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             28 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             30 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             32 LOAD_NAME                3 (t)
             34 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             36 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             38 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       42

  6          40 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20

  7     >>   42 LOAD_NAME                4 (print)
             44 LOAD_NAME                3 (t)
             46 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             48 POP_TOP
             50 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20
        >>   52 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             54 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that for the `t == a` comparison,

```
  5          24 LOAD_NAME                3 (t)
             26 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             28 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             30 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
```

the code jumps to the instruction at bytecode index 20, which is the `FOR_ITER` instruction. The `continue` line is skipped entirely.

On the other hand, if the `t == a` check fails and the `t == b` check passes, then the code falls through the `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE` for the first comparison (because the first result is false) and the `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` for the second comparison (because the second result is true). The code ends up reaching this instruction:

```
  6          40 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           20
```

which is what the `continue` on line 6 compiles to.

---

On Python 3.10, the jump targets are different. On 3.10, we instead see

```
  5          24 LOAD_NAME                3 (t)
             26 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             28 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             30 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20 (to 40)
```

with the `POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE` now jumping to bytecode index 40, which is the `continue`. Thus, on 3.10, pdb now stops at the `continue` even when `t == a`. (Due to changes in instruction encoding, bytecode index 40 happens to be represented by an oparg of 20 on Python 3.10, which coincidentally happens to be the bytecode index the Python 3.9 bytecode was jumping to. This confused me for a while before I figured out what was going on.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is interesting that you step through the byte code.  I'm still wondering why (at the programming logic level), why the instructions should behave differently based on which part of the conditional evaluates to True.  From a logic standpoint, python must have a 'reason' to behave like this when `t==a`.  I'd like to know what that reason is.